# Kinect Fusion get location

Tags: c#, kinect

So I worked with Kinect fusion and one of the cool things I saw in some videos and in their research paper, is that you can track/estimate where the kinect is.
I have tried to find some kind of way of doing it, but misserably failed.

Does anyone have experience with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by using the worldToCamera Matrix4.

It can transform any mesh spot to correct camera coordinates.